# unexpected result with char array and fork

Tags: c, arrays, char, fork

I'm trying to do a program with fork() in C but when I create a char array inside my code the program produces a unexpected result.(Instead of create 5 five sons it creates 6 sons? And the father?)

The code is this

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUMPROC 5

int main (int argc, char *args[]){
    //UNCOMMENTTHIS LINE
    //char a[] = {'a','b','c','d','\0'};
    int i;
    pid_t status[NUMPROC];
    for(i = 0; i< NUMPROC; i++){
        status[i] = fork();
        //fork error
        if(status[i] == -1){
            perror("fork() error");
            exit(1);
        }
        //quit because I'm a son
        if(status[i] == 0)
            break;
    }

    //son
    if(status[i] == 0){
        printf("I'm son number: %i\n", i);
    }
    //father
    else{
        //wait sons
        for(i = 0; i < NUMPROC; i++){
            wait(&status[0]);
        }
        printf("Father terminated\n");
    }
 }
```

If you try to uncomment the array's line the result changes but this array is never used!

Can you explain me why??

Comment: What result changes?

Comment: `if(status[i] == 0)` is outside the for, so `i == NUMPROC`: invokes UB.

Comment: I just tried it with Eclipse, with the line commented the output is:
`I'm son number: 0
I'm son number: 1
I'm son number: 2
I'm son number: 3
I'm son number: 4
Father terminated`
With the line un-commented the output is:
`I'm son number: 0
I'm son number: 1
I'm son number: 2
I'm son number: 5
I'm son number: 3
I'm son number: 4`

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  1) it is missing the statement: `#include <unistd.h>`  for the `fork()` function.  Suggest adding that statement.   2) it is missing the statements: `#include <sys/types.h>
       #include <sys/wait.h>` for the `wait()` funciton.  Suggest adding those statements.  3) the parameter: `argc` and the parameter `argv` are unused.   Suggest using the main() signature of: `int main( void )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//son
if(status[i] == 0){
    printf("I'm son number: %i\n", i);
}
```

Code above doesn't work correctly in the father, for I will be equal to `NUMPROC`, which should be `NUMPROC - 1`.

This is a simple array index out of bounds problem. Value of `status[NUMPROC]` is uninitialized, it's value could be affected by the `char` array, so you will get different result.

Answer (score 2):

Add the lines indicated and the problem will be obvious:

```
//son
if (i >= NUMPROC)     // add this line
    printf("ACK\n");  // and this line

if(status[i] == 0){
    printf("I'm son number: %i\n", i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be a misunderstanding about when/where each possible return state from the call to `fork()`  occurs and how to handle the child state.

all the child actions need to be within the `for()` loop

all the parent actions (except the call to `wait()` need to be within the `for()` loop

The child actions must terminate in a call to `exit()`

Suggest the following code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired operation
3. incorporates the initial comments on OPs question

and now, the proposed code

```
#include <stdlib.h>    // exit(), EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <stdio.h>     // printf()
#include <unistd.h>    // fork(), pid_t
#include <sys/types.h> // #defines for waitpid()
#include <sys/wait.h>  // waitpid()

#define NUMPROC (5)

int main ( void )
{
    int i;
    pid_t pid[NUMPROC] = {0};

    for(i = 0; i< NUMPROC; i++)
    {
        pid[i] = fork();

        switch( pid[i] )
        {
            case -1: // error
                perror("fork() error");
                // keep going, 
                // so if any current child's exit,
                // they do not become zombie processes
                break;

            case 0: // child
                printf("I'm son number: %i\n", i);
                exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
                break;

            default: // parent
                break;
        } // end switch
    } // end for

    //  only father gets here
    //wait sons
    for(i = 0; i < NUMPROC; i++)
    {
        if( -1 != pid[i] )
        { // then child process successfully created
            waitpid( pid[i], NULL, 0 );
        }
    }
    printf("Father terminated\n");
 }
```

here is the output from a typical run of the program:

```
I'm son number: 0
I'm son number: 1
I'm son number: 4
I'm son number: 2
I'm son number: 3
Father terminated
```